# Connect OBDSim to Torque on Windows through Bluetooth

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, elm327

I'm trying to install OBDSim on Win7 but am running into some trouble. My end goal is to run OBDSim as a bluetooth ELM327 OBDII Simulator and connect to it using the Torque app on my Android device.

I watched a video on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dMjo5ySbcc) that demos exactly what I am trying to simulate but it was running Lubuntu 12.04.

I've been reading through posts on mp3car and other posts on stackoverflow over the last week but I'm still a little lost. I'm not sure exactly how obdsim makes use of com0com to get my bluetooth dongle to connect with Torque on my phone. Heres what I have so far:

- I've paired my Android device to my computer
- I've installed com0com and have a CNCA0 <-> COM5 pair set up.
- I set the incoming COM Port to be COM5
- I'm running the obdsimwindows-2011-06-11 build as suggested (Although
  -b is giving an invalid option.. Also bluetooth isn't listed under --help either. Does this version support bt??)
- I am able to launch the gui successfully using 'obdsim.exe -g gui_fltk -w COM5'
- Torque still isn't being able to connect and read from the simulator.

I think theres one more  big step I'm missing, but I'm not sure what it is. I found this correspondence (http://icculus.org/pipermail/obdgpslogger/2012-January/000122.html) which sort of resembles where I'm at, but I don't know how to the bind and sdptool commands translate to windows (that was a linux problem).

Has anyone tried to set up OBDSim on Windows and connected to their Android device via bluetooth successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The man page, right under the bluetooth heading, says that bluetooth is not supported in windows.

http://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/manpages/render/obdsim.txt

Comment: Hey Timm.. I emailed Gary (the creator of obdsim) and he replied back with this which makes me think that it is possible and the site just hasn't been updated yet:

----------------------
I believe it works fine. Here's a message from someone who's doing
it successfully:

   -I took your pre-last-windows-build of obdsim for windows
   (obdsimwindows-2011-06-11.zip, pre last because the newest one has no   gui_fltk plugin).

Comment: -Then I had to pair my Nexus with my computer via bluetooth, after the connection was established i could read out a serial port (see attachment 'bluetoothSettings1.jpg') in my bluetooth settings. If you can't see any in- or outcomming forwarding for serial ports, you have create an empty one (just click on 'add' then 'Incoming ...' and 'OK', then reconnect your device, windows installs some drives and then one or two or more serial ports should be shown).

Comment: That's all, then you can call obdsim.exe with :

   'obdsim.exe -g gui_fltk -w COM:SERIALPORT:' so in my case : 'obdsim.exe
   -g gui_fltk -w COM7' or 'obdsim.exe -g gui_fltk -w COM9'.
---------------------

Comment: I tried following those instructions. However it still doesn't work. I'm kind of dead in the water right now so any help would be appreciated. 

Thanks,
-Mahir

Sorry for the multiple comments.. Couldn't post it all in one

Comment: I'm not sure how to help unfortunately.  I've never tried to do it in Windows.  I just remembered seeing that in the man page.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks anyways Timm.. I'm trying it again on ubuntu. Got it to build.. still need to configure BT though

Comment: Hey Mahir. I'm also trying to connect obdsim via bluetooth on both ubuntu and windows, but ended in vain. Please help me, if you are succeeded.

Comment: @Mahir, I have followed the exact same way you have mentioned. It worked for me.

Comment: @malintha yeah I tried it again and got it to work on a different computer. Don't know what I was doing wrong earlier but everything is good now :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

One more answer from stackoverflow which worked perfectly for us.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25763606/739262

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Win7 and it works with the -w switch ...trying to make it work on VM win7 in a Mac host still having issues.

FYI it also works thru a tcp socket I have a win7 VM where I run OBDSim and thru a redirector tcp to COM make it available from outside the VM it works ... bunch of tools to do the redirecting but none worked 4 me ended up writing my own simple socket redirector to COM in Win7. Tested it on the Mac thru a basic iOS App I wrote on the iOS simulator.